# SQL - Equivalent Django Query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a table

```
+----+------------+
| id | day        |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2006-10-08 |
|  2 | 2006-10-08 |
|  3 | 2006-10-09 |
|  4 | 2006-10-09 |
|  5 | 2006-10-09 |
|  5 | 2006-10-09 |
|  6 | 2006-10-10 |
|  7 | 2006-10-10 |
|  8 | 2006-10-10 |
|  9 | 2006-10-10 |
+----+------------
```

I want to group by the **frequency and its count**, for example

> Since there's a date `2006-10-08` that appears twice, hence frequency `2` and there is only one date that appears twice , hence total dates `1`.

Another example

> `2006-10-10` and `2006-10-09` both appears 4 times, hence frequency `4` and total dates with frequency 4 are `2`.

I'm expecting output like the following

```
+----------+--------------------------------+
| Freuency | Total Dates with frequency N   |
+----------+--------------------------------+
|  1       | 0                              |
|  2       | 1                              |
|  3       | 0                              |
|  4       | 2                              |
|  n       | f(n)                           |
+----------+--------------------------------+
```

I have a SQL Query, written after a considerable thought, and I was wondering what the equivalent Django query would be?

```
select freq, count(*)
from (select day, count(*) as freq
      from test 
      group by day
     ) d
group by freq;
```

Comment: Can you give us your Django models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Count
MyModel.objects.values('day').annotate(frequency=count('day')).order_by('frequency')
```